# OpenGL ES Vertex / Indicies

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm just starting to learn OpenGL ES but am having some trouble understanding how the vertex and indices work. My current understanding is that a Vertex is a point on the shape itself, and that the indices represent the 'triangles' within the vertex points. I'm following a tutorial that has me define the vertex and indices points as below...

Vertex data

-1.0f, -1.0f
1.0f, -1.0f 
-1.0f, 1.0f 
1.0f, 1.0f

indices data

0,3,1,
0,2,3

I understand that defining indices should always start at one vertex but to me these numbers just dont add up. When I draw this on paper it looks like the actual image drawn should be two triangles together that create a 'crown' shape. Can someone explain why this is actually drawing a square instead of the 'crown' that I am expecting?

Source code for the Square class:

```
public class Square {

private FloatBuffer mFVertexBuffer;
private ByteBuffer mColorBuffer;
private ByteBuffer mIndexBuffer;

public Square() {

    // 2D Points
    float[] square = {

    -1.0f, -1.0f, 
    1.0f, -1.0f, 
    -1.0f, 1.0f, 
    1.0f, 1.0f,         

    };

    byte maxColor = (byte) 225;

    /**
     * Each line below represents RGB + Alpha transparency
     */
    byte colors[] = {

    0, maxColor, 0, maxColor,
    0, maxColor, maxColor, maxColor,
    0, 0, 0, maxColor, 
    maxColor, 0, maxColor, maxColor,

    };

    //triangles
    byte[] indicies = {

            0,3,1,
            0,2,3

    };

    /**
     * Make sure that bytes are in correct order, otherwise they might be
     * drawn backwards
     */
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(square.length * 4);
    byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    mFVertexBuffer = byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
            .asFloatBuffer();
    mFVertexBuffer.put(square);
    mFVertexBuffer.position(0);

    mColorBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(colors.length);
    mColorBuffer.put(colors);
    mColorBuffer.position(0);

    mIndexBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indicies.length);
    mIndexBuffer.put(indicies);
    mIndexBuffer.position(0);
}

public void draw(GL10 gl) {

    /**
     * Make open GL only draw the front of the triangle (GL_CW = Graphics
     * Library Clockwise)
     * 
     * Back of triangle will not be drawn
     */
    gl.glFrontFace(GL11.GL_CW);

    /**
     * specifies number of elements per vertex
     * 
     * specifies floating point type
     * 
     * Sets stride = 0 bytes* (Stride allows to use different types of data
     * interchangably with opengl )
     */
    gl.glVertexPointer(2, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 0, mFVertexBuffer);

    // 4 because we are using 4 colors in our color bufer array
    gl.glColorPointer(4, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, mColorBuffer);

    /**
     * draws the image
     * 
     * first argument specifies geomety format
     */
    gl.glDrawElements(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
            mIndexBuffer);

    // Reset to CounterClockwise
    gl.glFrontFace(GL11.GL_CCW);

}
```

}

Let me know if more info is needed...

Comment: One thing to note, this isn't specifically an OpenGL-ES problem, you can run into this problem in any OpenGL context whether it be standard OpenGL, WebGL, GLES, or anything else.

Comment: Good thing to know, I was actually wondering about how much knowledge would hold across different versions of OpenGL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You defined four vertices:

```
2    3

0    1
```

Your indices then defined two triangles, 0-3-1:

```
     .
   ...
  ....
 .....
```

and 0-2-3:

```
.....
....
...
.
```

put together they form a square.

Comment: So why exactly do the vertexes line up this way? I thought they would be either clockwise or counter-clockwise around the square

Comment: OpenGL is like a game of connect-the-dots -- you specified four dots (vertexes), then you connected them.  The vertexes define the corners of each triangle (not a point within it), and the indices each specify a vertex (not a triangle).  The CW/CCW is for backface removal; if you did 0-1-3 and 0-3-2 you wouldn't see anything.

Comment: CW/CCW is for face orientation in general. Its primary use in most applications is for culling a certain side of a face, but it has other uses too. There are stencil operations that only apply to a single-side, for instance.

Comment: I understand now, the order that I define my vertex's actually matters (see the Square array in my original post) and will dictate exactly where the points are mapped as fadden has shown above! Knowing that, the indices are easy to map! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your indexes are correct, try drawing the bottom line then moving to the top verts.  If I am picturing your indexes correctly, they really are trying to draw a square.

Try:
0, 1, 3
0, 1, 2

Instead

**Edit**: Even I got the order mixed up, fixed for a mistake

Comment: The current indices that I am using actually do draw a square, but I'm confused as to why. Your indexes make a 90 degree triangle in the bottom right corner of where the square would normally be drawn. with the 90 angle in the bottom right corner.

Comment: One of the triangles is invisible because it's wound CCW.

Comment: Wow, even I get mixed up with base 0 v. base 1 array/index locations, I thought I was drawing the bottom 2 indexes of the horizon, but I was drawing the diagonal.  I'll fix it now.